# stop :before and element overlappting

Tags: css

I have a css class that has a pseudo :before class attached to it. The :before class is just a border but it is overlapping the text. I have tried padding but it's still overlapping. Here is css code

```
 .chevron {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: #d1dce6;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        height: 40px;
        max-height: 40px;
    }
    .chevron:before  {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;

        border-left: 20px solid white;
        border-top: 20px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    }
```

[image]

How can I get some space between the white border (:before) and text

Edit 1: The css class is applied to a  element. Padding-left doesnt work.

```
 <th class="chevron" v-for="p in joinTo">{{p.description.trunc(30)}}</th>
```

Comment: can you give fiddle?

Comment: @DmytroLishtvan If you understand the problem, you don't need a fiddle. :)

Comment: try padding -left 30 or 40 px

Comment: I would like to see the HTML code that comes with this CSS :)

Comment: updated snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some padding in the parent element:

```
.chevron {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: #d1dce6;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    /* Add this line: */
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

**Tip:** Since you already have `left: 0`, you don't need to worry about the left alignment issues.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, if you don't want the overall size to increase because of padding you can use either of the two:

```
padding-left: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

```
text-indent: 50px;
```

Comment: Or `text-indent: 50px;` if you don't want to increase the element's size.

Comment: @Cons7an7ine Good one. Also you can use `box-sizing: border-box` so that it gives the same output. Nice one man.

Comment: @Abhi.Net Might be because other styles overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

You need add padding for parent element

```css
 .chevron {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: #d1dce6;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        height: 40px;
        max-height: 40px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
    .chevron:before  {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;

        border-left: 20px solid white;
        border-top: 20px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="chevron">sdsdsd</th>
          <th class="chevron">sdsdsd</th>
          <th class="chevron">sdsdsd</th>
          <th class="chevron">sdsdsd</th>
          <th class="chevron">sdsdsd</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Should have added one more thing.... The class is applied to a th element. I have tried padding-left , doesnt work.

Comment: @Abhi.Net added table. That's why i want your fiddle - because all work fine) try add !important to your padding